# How to change .env file path in Python?

Tags: python, environment-variables, env-file

My boss has changed his mind, want me to change `.env` file path.

We all know we can call `.env` variable as like this:

```
from decouple import config

variable_from_env = config('someVariableName')
```

And I know that we can call `.env` file outside of root path like this:

```
from decouple import config, Config, RepositoryEnv

envFile = Config(RepositoryEnv("../.env"))

variable_from_env = envFile('someVariableName')
```

We'll move the .env file to parent path. But there are so much variables which have called by using `config('someVariableName')`

Is there any easy way to achive this, or should I use `Config(RepositoryEnv("../.env"))`?

Comment: Why not just set `config = Config(RepositoryEnv('../.env'))`, instead of introducing a new `envFile` variable?

Comment: @larsks sorry for my poor python knowledge. Is it acceptable to define this name to a variable?

Comment: You can create your own variable named `config` rather than importing it from the `decouple` module. You can name variables pretty much anything you want, with the exception of a few language keywords.

Comment: Thank you. Please write it as answer

Comment: I believe this is actually a duplicate of another question. I think you'll find some answers there that will be helpful.